# Translatepress breaking javascript. Adds defer to script tags automatically

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using translatepress to translate my company's website, but it's causing one of our calculators written in javascript to not load.

I've found it's adding "defer" to a bunch of our  tags.

Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?

I've tried:

- Disabling "Fix missing dynamic content"
- Disabling "dynamic translation"

But none has worked.

Comment: Did you open the inspector and looked at the console? What error do you get?

Comment: @Kees Yup, I get errors such as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setLocaleData')" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined".

Comment: @Kees An example of the first error is this code: 
`<script type='text/javascript' id='wp-i18n-js-after'>
wp.i18n.setLocaleData( { 'text direction\u0004ltr': [ 'ltr' ] } );
</script>`

And the example of the second error is: 
`<script type='text/javascript' id='lodash-js-after'>
window.lodash = _.noConflict();
</script>`

Of which, these lines are exactly the same in the english version of this page. The only difference is that 48 other script tags are being deferred in the french version

Comment: Did you try to switch other plugins off to see if one plugin causes this problem? And can you track down something in your debug log?